# Which languages are supported by Firebase ML Smart Reply?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I searched official documentation and forums but failed to find any signs of support for different languages.
Does Firebase ML Smart Reply support German, Spanish, Russian?

Answer (score 2):

It only supports English for now.

See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/generate-smart-replies